# How did this user post an answer *after* the question was put on hold?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259635/260841) was put on hold at 16:31.

However, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259652/260841) was then post *afterwards* 3 minutes later at 16:34.

How did the user do this? I thought answers were not allowed to be accepted after a post has been closed...?

I *guess* that this was possible because the user had started writing *before* the question was closed so it got through, but if this is the case, then this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because the 'Post answer' button should check to see whether the question is closed or not before allowing it, just like it checks to see whether the question has been deleted.

Comment: @Oded how likely is a feature-request to make the check server-side going to be accepted...? If a question is put on hold, it *generally* means it will produce stupid answers (as the one I linked to is), or irrelevant, so it shouldn't be allowed to happen...

Comment: This is [meta-tag:status-bydesign], so not very likely. The server side check is lenient for a reason.